# How to send response from Azure Databricks the UI in real-time?

Tags: azure, postman, databricks, job-scheduling, mlflow

I have registered my ML model using Mlflow in Azure Databricks, and have a model URL.
Now, in another notebook of Databricks, I am preparing data(retrieved from the SQL) and filtering it based on the input parameters fetched as a RestAPI from Postman.
Next, I am using this prepared data frame(max. 20 records) to get the prediction for each row. And, converting this data frame into JSON serializable format to send it as a response to Postman.
The notebook runtime is 2 secs.

Every time a request is got, a databricks job is run, and the response is sent. I am not sure why each job's runtime is 12 secs or more(despite the notebook runtime being 2 secs. only).
What I actually I am looking into is to send a curated response, that'll have some additional parameters along with the prediction, in form of a RestAPI in milliseconds(as it is realtime).

Everything is done in Databricks, itself.

I believe I am somewhere lacking in understanding which architecture shall help us achieve my requirement. Kindly help me understand the same. Thanks a lot, in advance.

Comment: whats running the job here the databricks scheduler or are you using something else like datafactory?

Comment: I am using the databricks scheduler for running the job.

Comment: if i understand you correctly, you are sending an API response but the notebook takes 2 seconds to execute and when doing it via a job scheduler it takes n number of seconds. I think the issue is your using databricks as an API framework which i think is not its intended use, it uses a lot of backend JVM's i don't have much exp in putting ML models into prod but i feel like this isn't the right way. Happy to be proven wrong though as I totally love databricks.

Comment: I am as well quiet new to this, hence, I am not sure, if I am at doing the right way. Also, could you please let me know how to send an API as a response without scheduling a job(as it's taking a lot of backend time)!